# Manipulate the build date of an bios version

Tags: reverse-engineering, bios

I have updated to a new bios version which is probably corrupt. Now I can't fall back to an older bios version because the build date always has to be newer than the currently installed bios.

Is there a safe way to manipulate the build date? In windows it is called "Date modified"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay never mind I just figured it out by myself. I just had to re safe it.